# CartoDB Update API

Tags: carto, api, update

Im uploading a csv with the following command: (attached)

```
curl -v -F file=@/var/www/html/map.csv "https://account.cartodb.com/api/v1/imports/?api_key={apiKey}"
```

I had item_queue_id from the response "a157fd40-10ae-4976-afa1-c0d0599042ee" and it should be the table ID according to the docs.

Then I try to update the table with the following command, the console shows a lot of JS like code and then nothing happens.

```
curl -v -F file=@/var/www/html/map.csv "https://account.cartodb.com/api/v1/imports/a157fd40-10ae-4976-afa1-c0d0599042ee?api_key={apiKey}"
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item_queue_id corresponds to the ID of the import process, but not to your table. This was incorrectly said in the documentation and we have just fixed it.

If you want to update a table that you have previously uploaded then you need to use the [SQL API](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/sql-api.html), or build a Sync table from the import API too (this requires that your account is able to create them and also that the file is uploaded to the Internet, a table cannot be synced with a local file in your computer).

To get extra information about the import process, as the table name (to use the SQL API afterwards) you can request:

https://account.cartodb.com/api/v1/imports/a157fd40-10ae-4976-afa1-c0d0599042ee?api_key=key

Comment: I was not choosing the SQL api because there are like 10000 records. Im going with sinced tables.